# How to get video from webcam in a "Picture in Picture mode"

Tags: quicktime, screen-capture, photo-booth, picture-in-picture

While recording a screencast with QuickTime, I want to get video from the webcam in small window overlay. I can use photobooth video preview, but it's always too large and has lots of chrome.

This would save me having to rely on third party premium apps.

What are my options?

Comment: should be obvious enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried starting a New Movie Recording first, selecting Float on Top from the view menu and then starting a New Screen Recording? Just tested it and it did a great job of a resizable PIP affect all in QT.